# route binding for optional parameters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have route like this:

```
$this->get('/{citySlug}/{catSlug1?}/{catSlug2?}/{sightSlug?}', function () {
  return 'Hello World';
});
```

How can I bind it in boot() function in **RouteServiceProvider.php** to check?

I try this:

```
Route::bind('citySlug', function ($citySlug, $route) { ... });

   Route::bind('catSlug1', function ($citySlug, $route) { ... });

   Route::bind('catSlug2', function ($catSlug2, $route) { ... });

   Route::bind('catSlug3', function ($catSlug3, $route) { ... });

   Route::bind('sightSlug', function ($sightSlug, $route) { ... });
```

but it wrong for optional parameters...what is wrong in the above?

**update:**

```
example.com/city_slug/cat1/cat2  It works.

example.com/city_slug/cat1/cat2/sight_slug It works.

example.com/city_slug/cat1/sight_slug It not works!
```

Comment: What is the error you have? I see you asked this question yesterday, too. However, the bindings look correct and the optional parameters also look correct.

Comment: I could solve more than yesterday. please check my update. My problem is for dynamic category and subcategory....I know it must be so simple for a laravel worker...But I couldn't any doc or help in internet...

Comment: You cant do that for optional parameters. `sight_slug` in your last example will be considered `catSlug2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely it will not work. Try to understand the route you are using:-

```
$this->get('/{citySlug}/{catSlug1?}/{catSlug2?}/{sightSlug?}', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
citySlug i.e. mandatory according to your route
catSlug1,catSlug2,sightSlug i.e this is not manadtory because you added question mark as per laravel documentation
```

Now you are tryig to access this url :-

```
example.com/city_slug/cat1/sight_slug --- Definitely it will not work because
                                          your **sight_slug** is treat like **catSlug2** 
                                          that's why its not working
```

**Solution**:-

```
For this you can use $_GET parameters and create one route something like that:-
$this->get('/filter-query', function () {
   return 'Hello World';
});
```

Now Your url will look like this:-

```
example.com/filter-query?citySlug=cityname&cat1=catvalue&cat2=&sightSlug=sightslugvalue
```

After that in function you can echo the $_GET and your problem will be solved.
Hope it helps!